does the verb provide get gerund or infinitive?
Would it be correct to say 'We can say that sports provide individuals to channelize their energy into a beneficial activity.'

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"to channel their energy..." would be preferable over the current phrasing: while "channelize" does have its own dictionary entry https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/channelize, this is the first time I've ever seen the word used, and so I initially assumed it was a mistake (others might, as well). It does not seem to be very common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=channel%2Cchannelize&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

No, provide does not take the same kind of complement as allow.
{subject} PROVIDES  {object} (with) {SOMETHING}.
{subject} ALLOWS {object} to {VERB}
